# How to parse over JSON data to bind dependent dropdowns?

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have JSON of this format:
[image]

> {"Engineering":{ "Electrical Engineering":{ "Research
> Staff":["research associate","research sciencetist","senior research
> sciencetist"], "Non-tenure-track":["research professaor","associate
> research professor","assistant research profesor","clinical
> profesor","clinical associate profesor","clinical assistant
> profesor","visiting profesor","visiting associate profesor","visiting
> assistant profesor"], "Professional Staff":["business
> manager","university research administrator","department
> administrative assistant"]},
>
> "Computer Science":{ "Research Staff":["research associate","research
> sciencetist","senior research sciencetist"], "Tenured":["distinguished
> professor","professor","associate professor","assistant professor"],
> "Teaching Faculty":["distinguished professor","professor","associate
> professor","assistant professor"]},
>
> "Computer Engineering":{"Tenured":["distinguished
> professor","professor","associate professor","assistant professor"],
> "Teaching Faculty":["lecturer","senior lecturer","adjunct professor"],
> "Professional Staff":["business manager","university research
> administrator","department administrative assistant"]}
>
> },
>
> "Science":{ "Physics":{ "Research Staff":["research
> associate","research sciencetist","senior research sciencetist"],
> "Teaching Faculty":["lecturer","senior lecturer","adjunct professor"],
> "Non-Tenured-Track":["research professaor","associate research
> professor","assistant research profesor","clinical profesor","clinical
> associate profesor","clinical assistant profesor","visiting
> profesor","visiting associate profesor","visiting assistant
> profesor"]},
>
> "Chemistry":{ "Tenured":["distinguished
> professor","professor","associate professor","assistant professor"],
> "Teaching Faculty":["lecturer","senior lecturer","adjunct professor"],
> "Non-Tenured-Track":["research professaor","associate research
> professor","assistant research profesor","clinical profesor","clinical
> associate profesor","clinical assistant profesor","visiting
> profesor","visiting associate profesor","visiting assistant
> profesor"]}
>
> }
>
> }

Here I want to bind 4 drop-downs with values as:
College: {"Engineering", "Science"}
Department: {"Electrical Engineering", "Computer Science"} when College "Engineering" is selected and {"Physics", "Chemistry"} when "Science" college is selected.

Also, within "Electrical Engineering" department we got to bind {"Research Staff", "Non-tenure-track", "Professional Staff"} into Position Type drop-down and based on its selection I need to bind  Position Title drop-down as {"research associate","research sciencetist","senior research sciencetist"} if "Research Staff" Position Type is selected and so on....

How can I parse through this static JSON data and bind those drop-downs respective to each other's selected value.

Comment: Google `java json parser` and you will have a good starting point.

Comment: thanks that's the best answer! @Jean-Paul but just how to parse it in client side and bind it to corresponding drop downs that is my question!

Comment: You have tagged both `Java` and `jQuery`. With which language do you want to parse it?

Comment: I love to have jQuery cause I already parsed this JSON data using Jackson now trying to bind on client page using jQuery parsing for JSON object of this given format!

Comment: Then why did you tag `Java`? Now Constantin has written a beautiful answer which, apparently, doesn't use the preferred language. Don't you think that's misleading and unfair to the people trying to provide an answer for you? Please next time try to tag your questions correctly and unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to do this with XML. Let me provide you a full solution using XML. If you want to try your hand using a JSON parser, you will have to adapt this solution for your own needs. OK, let's start ... First, go to this site ...

http://www.json.org/java/

... and download the following files into a new java package called : `org.json;`

- JSONArray.java
- JSONException.java
- JSONObject.java
- JSONString.java
- JSONStringer.java
- JSONTokener.java
- JSONWriter.java
- XML.java
- XMLTokener.java

I did this myself and wrote a small program to convert your JSON string to XML:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getJSONSting() );
    String xml = XML.toString(json);
    System.out.println(xml);
}

private static final String getJSONSting() {
    String data = "{\"Engineering\":{ \"Electrical Engineering\":{ \"Research Staff\":[\"research associate\",\"research sciencetist\",\"senior research sciencetist\"], \"Non-tenure-track\":[\"research professaor\",\"associate research professor\",\"assistant research profesor\",\"clinical profesor\",\"clinical associate profesor\",\"clinical assistant profesor\",\"visiting profesor\",\"visiting associate profesor\",\"visiting assistant profesor\"], \"Professional Staff\":[\"business manager\",\"university research administrator\",\"department administrative assistant\"]},";
           data += "\"Computer Science\":{ \"Research Staff\":[\"research associate\",\"research sciencetist\",\"senior research sciencetist\"], \"Tenured\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"]}, \"Computer Engineering\":{\"Tenured\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"lecturer\",\"senior lecturer\",\"adjunct professor\"], \"Professional Staff\":[\"business manager\",\"university research administrator\",\"department administrative assistant\"]}";
           data += "},";
           data += "\"Science\":{ \"Physics\":{ \"Research Staff\":[\"research associate\",\"research sciencetist\",\"senior research sciencetist\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"lecturer\",\"senior lecturer\",\"adjunct professor\"], \"Non-Tenured-Track\":[\"research professaor\",\"associate research professor\",\"assistant research profesor\",\"clinical profesor\",\"clinical associate profesor\",\"clinical assistant profesor\",\"visiting profesor\",\"visiting associate profesor\",\"visiting assistant profesor\"]},";
           data += "\"Chemistry\":{ \"Tenured\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"lecturer\",\"senior lecturer\",\"adjunct professor\"], \"Non-Tenured-Track\":[\"research professaor\",\"associate research professor\",\"assistant research profesor\",\"clinical profesor\",\"clinical associate profesor\",\"clinical assistant profesor\",\"visiting profesor\",\"visiting associate profesor\",\"visiting assistant profesor\"]}";
           data += "}";
           data += "}";
        return data;
    }
}
```

Here it is in XML format, you will notice the illegal use of spaces in tags. This is addressed in my solution so you may study the code to see how I corrected the problem ...

```
<Engineering>
    <Computer Science>
        <Tenured>distinguished professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>associate professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>assistant professor</Tenured>
        <Research Staff>research associate</Research Staff>
        <Research Staff>research sciencetist</Research Staff>
        <Research Staff>senior research sciencetist</Research Staff>
        <Teaching Faculty>distinguished professor</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>professor</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>associate professor</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>assistant professor</Teaching Faculty>
    </Computer Science>
    <Electrical Engineering>
        <Professional Staff>business manager</Professional Staff>
        <Professional Staff>university research administrator</Professional Staff>
        <Professional Staff>department administrative assistant</Professional Staff>
        <Research Staff>research associate</Research Staff>
        <Research Staff>research sciencetist</Research Staff>
        <Research Staff>senior research sciencetist</Research Staff>
        <Non-tenure-track>research professaor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>associate research professor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>assistant research profesor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>clinical profesor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>clinical associate profesor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>clinical assistant profesor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>visiting profesor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>visiting associate profesor</Non-tenure-track>
        <Non-tenure-track>visiting assistant profesor</Non-tenure-track>
    </Electrical Engineering>
    <Computer Engineering>
        <Tenured>distinguished professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>associate professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>assistant professor</Tenured>
        <Professional Staff>business manager</Professional Staff>
        <Professional Staff>university research administrator</Professional Staff>
        <Professional Staff>department administrative assistant</Professional Staff>
        <Teaching Faculty>lecturer</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>senior lecturer</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>adjunct professor</Teaching Faculty>
    </Computer Engineering>
</Engineering>
<Science>
    <Chemistry>
        <Tenured>distinguished professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>associate professor</Tenured>
        <Tenured>assistant professor</Tenured>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>research professaor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>associate research professor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>assistant research profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>clinical profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>clinical associate profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>clinical assistant profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>visiting profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>visiting associate profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>visiting assistant profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Teaching Faculty>lecturer</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>senior lecturer</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>adjunct professor</Teaching Faculty>
    </Chemistry>
    <Physics>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>research professaor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>associate research professor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>assistant research profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>clinical profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>clinical associate profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>clinical assistant profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>visiting profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>visiting associate profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Non-Tenured-Track>visiting assistant profesor</Non-Tenured-Track>
        <Research Staff>research associate</Research Staff>
        <Research Staff>research sciencetist</Research Staff>
        <Research Staff>senior research sciencetist</Research Staff>
        <Teaching Faculty>lecturer</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>senior lecturer</Teaching Faculty>
        <Teaching Faculty>adjunct professor</Teaching Faculty>
    </Physics>
</Science>
```

If you got this far, you can complete the rest of the project by copying over the following classes. I have tested the solution and it seems to work fine.

This is what it looks like completed ...

[image]

The first class is placed in package `org.combobox`:

```
package org.combobox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CleanNode {

  private String _name;
  private List<CleanNode> _nodes = new ArrayList<CleanNode>();

  public CleanNode(Node node) {
    _name = node.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE ? node.getNodeValue() : node.getNodeName();
  }

  private String getName() {
    return _name;
  }

  public CleanNode addChild(Node node) {
    CleanNode foundNode = null;
    String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    for(CleanNode child : _nodes){
      if(child.getName().equals(nodeName)) {
        foundNode = child;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(foundNode == null) {
      foundNode = new CleanNode(node);
        _nodes.add(foundNode);
    }
    return foundNode;
  }

  public List<CleanNode> getNodes(){
    return _nodes;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return _name.replace("_", " ");
  }
}
```

The second class is placed in package `org.combobox`:

```
package org.combobox;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ComboBoxChain extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static String _xml;
    private Node _root;
    private CleanNode _cleanNode;

  public ComboBoxChain() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    super("ComboBox Chain");
    setUIFont (new javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,14));
    buildXML();
    cleanXML();
    _root = parse(_xml);
    _cleanNode = new CleanNode(_root);
    addCleanNodeChildren(_cleanNode, _root);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(new ComboPanel(_cleanNode), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }

  private void addCleanNodeChildren(CleanNode cleanNode, Node node) {
    if(node.getChildNodes() != null) {
        NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
      for(int index = 0; index < children.getLength(); index++){
        Node child = children.item(index);
        CleanNode cleanChild = cleanNode.addChild(child);
        addCleanNodeChildren(cleanChild, child);
      }
    }
  }

  protected Node getRootNode() {
    return _root;
  }

  private void cleanXML() {
    String xml = _xml;
    int beginIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;

    for(int index = 0; index < _xml.length(); index++) {
      if(_xml.charAt(index) == '<') {
        beginIndex = index;
      }
      else if (_xml.charAt(index) == '>') {
        endIndex = index;
        String originalTag = _xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex + 1);
        String newTag = originalTag;
        while(newTag.contains(" ")) {
          newTag = newTag.replace(" ", "_");
        }
        xml = xml.replace(originalTag, newTag);
      }
    }
    _xml = xml;
  }

  private static final void buildXML() {
    String data = "{\"Engineering\":{ \"Electrical Engineering\":{ \"Research Staff\":[\"research associate\",\"research sciencetist\",\"senior research sciencetist\"], \"Non-tenure-track\":[\"research professaor\",\"associate research professor\",\"assistant research profesor\",\"clinical profesor\",\"clinical associate profesor\",\"clinical assistant profesor\",\"visiting profesor\",\"visiting associate profesor\",\"visiting assistant profesor\"], \"Professional Staff\":[\"business manager\",\"university research administrator\",\"department administrative assistant\"]},";
    data += "\"Computer Science\":{ \"Research Staff\":[\"research associate\",\"research sciencetist\",\"senior research sciencetist\"], \"Tenured\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"]}, \"Computer Engineering\":{\"Tenured\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"lecturer\",\"senior lecturer\",\"adjunct professor\"], \"Professional Staff\":[\"business manager\",\"university research administrator\",\"department administrative assistant\"]}";
    data += "},";
    data += "\"Science\":{ \"Physics\":{ \"Research Staff\":[\"research associate\",\"research sciencetist\",\"senior research sciencetist\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"lecturer\",\"senior lecturer\",\"adjunct professor\"], \"Non-Tenured-Track\":[\"research professaor\",\"associate research professor\",\"assistant research profesor\",\"clinical profesor\",\"clinical associate profesor\",\"clinical assistant profesor\",\"visiting profesor\",\"visiting associate profesor\",\"visiting assistant profesor\"]},";
    data += "\"Chemistry\":{ \"Tenured\":[\"distinguished professor\",\"professor\",\"associate professor\",\"assistant professor\"], \"Teaching Faculty\":[\"lecturer\",\"senior lecturer\",\"adjunct professor\"], \"Non-Tenured-Track\":[\"research professaor\",\"associate research professor\",\"assistant research profesor\",\"clinical profesor\",\"clinical associate profesor\",\"clinical assistant profesor\",\"visiting profesor\",\"visiting associate profesor\",\"visiting assistant profesor\"]}";
    data += "}";
    data += "}";

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    _xml = "<Root>" + XML.toString(json) + "</Root>";

    System.out.println(_xml);

  }

  private static final void setUIFont (javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource f){
    Enumeration<Object> keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object key = keys.nextElement();
      Object value = UIManager.get (key);
      if (value != null && value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource) {
        UIManager.put (key, f);
      }
    }
  }

  private static final Node parse(String XMLContent) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XMLContent)));
    return document.getDocumentElement();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        ComboBoxChain frame;
        try {
          frame = new ComboBoxChain();
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The third class is placed in package `org.combobox`:

```
package org.combobox;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ComboPanel extends JPanel  {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static final String DEPARTMENT = "Department";
  private static final String PROGRAM = "Program";
  private static final String FACULTY = "Faculty";
  private static final String ACADEMIC_RANK = "Academic Rank";

  private JComboBox<CleanNode> _department;
  private JComboBox<CleanNode> _program;
  private JComboBox<CleanNode> _faculty;
  private JComboBox<CleanNode> _rank;

  private DependencyLink _rankLink;
  private DependencyLink _facultyLink;
  private DependencyLink _programLink;
  private DependencyLink _departmentLink;

  public ComboPanel(CleanNode root) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    addCombos(root);
  }

  private void addCombos(CleanNode root) {
    _department = new JComboBox<CleanNode>();
    _program = new JComboBox<CleanNode>();
    _faculty = new JComboBox<CleanNode>();
    _rank = new JComboBox<CleanNode>();

    _rankLink = new DependencyLink(_rank, null);
    _facultyLink = new DependencyLink(_faculty, _rankLink);
    _programLink = new DependencyLink(_program, _facultyLink);
    _departmentLink = new DependencyLink(_department, _programLink);
    _departmentLink.populate(root);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
    panel.add(new JLabel("                            " + DEPARTMENT + " : "));
    panel.add(_department);
    panel.add(new JLabel("                               " + PROGRAM + " : "));
    panel.add(_program);
    panel.add(new JLabel("                               " + FACULTY + " : "));
    panel.add(_faculty);
    panel.add(new JLabel("                         " + ACADEMIC_RANK + " : "));
    panel.add(_rank);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

The fourth and final class is placed in package `org.combobox`:

```
package org.combobox;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class DependencyLink implements ActionListener {

  private boolean _isLocked;
  private JComboBox<CleanNode>_combo;
  private DependencyLink _childLink;
  private CleanNode _previousNode;

  public DependencyLink(JComboBox<CleanNode>combo, DependencyLink childLink) {
    _combo = combo;
    _combo.addActionListener(this);
    _childLink = childLink;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    CleanNode node = (CleanNode)_combo.getSelectedItem();
    if(node != _previousNode) {
      updateChild();
      _previousNode = node;
    }
  }

  private void updateChild() {
    if( _childLink != null) {
      if(!_isLocked) {
        _childLink.populate((CleanNode)_combo.getSelectedItem());
      }
    }
  }

  public void populate(CleanNode parentNode) {
    _isLocked = true;
    _combo.removeAllItems();
    if(parentNode != null) {
      List<CleanNode> children = parentNode.getNodes();
      if(!children.isEmpty()) {
        for(CleanNode childNode : children) {
          _combo.addItem(childNode);
        }
        _combo.setSelectedItem(children.get(0));
      }
    }
    _isLocked = false;
    updateChild();
  }
}
```

Study the code and adapt it how you like for your own implementation.

Best of luck,
Constantin

Comment: How about doing this same thing on Client side not on Java Server Side? Suppose I got this whole json data in variable and then how to parse to bind to those dropdowns!

Comment: Let me send you the code that does this in xml, I will let you figure it out from there...how's that?   Give me a few minutes to finish it

Comment: Beautiful answer! Very impressive +1