# Populating dropdown list according to product id in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have a created a tab in product form for manufacturer. It has manufacturer_name and manufacturer_partno fields and some others. Each product has multiple manufacturers (one to many relationship). I want to get a dropdown of manufacturer_partno in add supplier form which are of the same product (same product id). I just want to know how this is possible. Please help me out if you can.

```
    // This is the product class extension
    class product_template(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    _columns = {
        'mrpproduct_partnumber': fields.char("Part Number", size=30, required=True),
        'mrpproduct_description': fields.text("Description", required=True),
        'mrpmanufacturers_ids': fields.one2many('mrpproduct.manufacturer','mrpproduct_id',string="Manufacturers"),
        'mrprohs_compliant': fields.boolean('RoHS Compliant'),
        'mrprequires_inspection': fields.boolean('Requires Inspection'),
        'mrpperishable': fields.boolean('Perishable'),
        'mrpperishabledate': fields.date('Perishable Date'),
        'mrpwashable': fields.boolean('Washable'),
        'mrphazardous': fields.boolean('Hazardous Material'),
        'mrphazardouspdf': fields.binary('MSDF PDF'),
        'mrpmsllevel_id': fields.many2one('mrp.msllevel','MSL Level'),
        'mrppackagingsize_id': fields.many2one('mrp.packagingsize','Packaging Size'),
        'mrpprocesstype_id': fields.many2one('mrp.processtype','Process Type'),
    }
    _order="mrpproduct_partnumber asc"


   // This is the manufacturer

class mrpproduct_manufacturer(osv.osv):
    _name = "mrpproduct.manufacturer"
    _columns = {
        'mrpmanufacturer_id': fields.many2one('mrp.manufacturers','Manufacturers'),
        'mrpmanufacturer_pno': fields.char("Manufacturer Part Number", size=30, required=True),
        'mrpmanufacturer_preference': fields.selection([('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5'),('6','6'),('7','7'),('8','8'),('9','9'),], string="Priority"),
        'mrpdatasheet': fields.binary('Data Sheet'),
        'mrpproduct_id': fields.many2one('product.template','Manufacturer'),
    }
    _order="mrpmanufacturer_preference desc"
```

Comment: I am afraid I do not know this particular programming language, however if your question is how to create a dependency chain of combo boxes together, I provided an elegant solution in java in another post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372818/how-to-parse-over-json-data-to-bind-dependent-dropdowns/31373263#31373263

Comment: Thanks @Constantin but this is specific to Odoo which is a Python framework for ERP systems.

Comment: OK, I was referring to the pattern used for such a task. Perhaps you can use the pattern, adapting it from Java to Python

Comment: I was googling and found this ... may help?  https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/when-changing-the-value-of-this-combobox-the-data-will-show-the-other-combobox-in-openerp-37128

Comment: Thanks alot for the interest, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem